# What are my accommodation options when doing a road trip in the Czech republic with children?

Tags: accommodation, road-trips, czech-republic

I am planning a road trip to the Czech republic. Everywhere I read that the czech republic is a relatively cheap destination. However, whenever searching online I can only find quite expensive options (>75 Euro per night). Even camp sites charge quite hefty fees. I suspect that regarding the camp sites, more affordable camp site will be available with camp sites without an online reservation system.

However, what are my options in the Czech republic if I consider camping one side of the spectrum and bungalow park/hotel the other side of the spectrum given that we are traveling with small children.

Comment: I was once in Prague. In my opinion, Czech Rep is not that cheap. You could try looking for B&B. A good one is like a hotel room, minus some hotel facilities.

Answer (score 2):

Except for Prague, Czech Republic is actually a quite cheap place. You can easily eat a full meal with a beer for ~5€. But since you ask for accommodation, I would look for "Penzion" - something like a small hotel. I have stayed in Penzions where I paid ~15€ for one room. Rooms were usually simple, but clean and definitely OK for that price! The tricky thing is that they won't always have a homepage (or only a Czech one). If you want to book ahead, I would either try via a local tourist information, who will be happy to help you find something nice, or check in a travel guide listing for Penzion names and email addresses.

Comment: If they don't have an English website, can I expect them to speak English?

Answer (score 1):

This is reply to @svick comment on @traindriver answer, because I don't have reputation to comment. It depends on age. Older generation don't speak English, but younger usualy speak english.